# How could I request a certain number (digit) with a certain times to be inserted in an input element?

Tags: html, validation, input, format, pattern-matching

How could I request a certain digit with a certain times to be inserted in an input element?

I need to request from The users to input three times a certain digit, let we say number 9, in the text or password field, in any format..

How could I do that using HTML5 or any other way?

If I had this code:

```
<td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="9" pattern="\d+" title="9 numbers only" placeholder="9 numbers only"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" /></td>
```

Then, my required pattern to be as example: ("x" is any digit)

xxx999xxx

Or:
x9x9x9xxx

Or:
9xxx9xxx9

Or:
x9xxxx99x

**It doesn't matter the format, the matter is 3 times of number 9 to be inserted every time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tool for Regular Expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

This pattern should work: `[^9.]*9[^9.]*9[^9.]*9[^9.]*`

Comment: gskinner.com/RegExr/. a great tool, Thanks. But now I have a lot of patterns, and one only acceptable in input elements, how can I deal with it, please?

Comment: Sorry. My pattern is not working because `.*` is a sequence of characters (9 is a character). :(

Comment: It's working, but I lost "integers only" pattern..! I need all of these patterns (9 digits & any 3 zeros), is there any way to do so, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frequecy of the character in javascript like

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        alert ('hi');
        var arr="sandeeep".split('');
        var uniqs = {};

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            uniqs[arr[i]] = (uniqs[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
        }
         var countarr = { val: arr[0], count: 1 };
        for(var u in uniqs) {
            if(countarr.count < uniqs[u]) { countarr= { val: u, count: uniqs[u] }; }
        }
        alert( countarr.count);
    </script>
```

from the above code

```
      alert( countarr.count);
```

you can check max count from countarr.count and validate it