# How could I request a certain digit (e.g. 0) to be entered once in an input element?

Tags: php, forms, validation, input, passwords

How could I request from users to enter a certain digit with certain times to be inserted in an input element?

I need to request from Them to input one time a certain digit, let we say number 0, in the text or password field, along with any other numbers from 1-4 only.

How could I do that using HTML5 or any other way? What is the pattern?

If I had this code:

```
<td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="4" pattern="\d+" title="3 numbers only, with 1 zero only" placeholder="3 numbers only, with 1 zero only"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" /></td>
```

Then, my required patterns to be as example: ("x" is any digit from 1 to 4 only)

```
xxx0
x0xx
0xxx
xx0x
```

and the rest of possible combinations.

NOTE agin:

- It doesn't matter the format, the matter is 1 time of number 0 to be
  inserted every time.
- Only numbers from 1 to 4 to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the user has to enter a 4 digit number. Within the number there has to be a single zero (and no more), but they can use the other numbers (1-4) as many times as they wish. Here is what I came up with:

```
^[1-4]{0,3}0[1-4]{0,3}$
```

You can see a working PHP example here: [PHPLiveRegEx.com Example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fvR)

Obviously your testing will have to take place server side or in javascript, but the above pattern will work.

## Edit

This section has nothing to do with the question, but is a quick help for the asker to help explain regular expressions. Links go to working examples on PHPLiveRegEx.com or RegEx101.com. RegEx101.com links included since it's nice enough to highlight the matches inside the text (the examples are otherwise the same).

1. [Simple example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/d9p) with the regular expression `Cat` ([Same example at RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tT9vG0/1))
2. [Simple example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/d9q) with the regular expression `[Cat]` ([Same example at RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kO6uP0/1))
3. [Example of finding a repeating pattern](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/d9r) ([Same example at RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQ1bG9/1))
4. [Combination example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/d9s) using concepts above ([Same example at RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xQ5vZ1/1))
5. [Finale example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/d9t) with asterisk. ([Same example at RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wR8mE6/1))

The only other thing to keep in mind is that different languages implement regular expressions differently, so what works for PHP may not work in another language exactly the same way. Usually some minor tweaking is all that is needed. The biggest thing is to just play around with it (I recommend using the sites I linked to for the above examples).

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828937/how-could-i-request-a-certain-number-digit-with-a-certain-times-to-be-inserted

Comment: I would be thankful if you got the simplest method ;)

Comment: See edit. You'd probably be better served trying to learn this for yourself. The question you linked was your own question that was almost identical to this one. You should have been able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I tried a lot! but I couldn't..!! I can't understand the logic! Would you guide me where to learn about it :)

Comment: If you look at the bottom of [PHPLiveRegEx.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) there is a cheat sheet of regular expressions. I would use that site to play around with various input and regular expressions. The other site I used when learning is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). The biggest thing to remember is a simple phrase can be a regular expression. `Cat` is a regular expression that will only match the 3 letter combo of "C", "a", and "t" in that order. `[Cat]` will match a single letter "C", "a", or "t". I'll add some working examples to help.